# Unable to set session.save_handler in my code

Tags: php, session, ini-set

After I upgraded PHP version of my website to 7.3, I started receiving this error message:

> Recoverable fatal error: ini_set(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name()

After my investigation, I found that the problem is in this line:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'user');
```

As I see in `php.ini`, the default value is "files". I try to change the value to files, but it's the same. Until PHP 7.1, everything works fine, but on PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3, I have this problem. I really can't understand why this function not working. It doesn't return any error, just a blank page with code 200 (not 500 as server error).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I already change to PHP 7.3. My problem is that this function is not working in PHP code.

Comment: I already check it, but i still can't understand why it's not working and how to fix it. That's why i wrote here, cuz i need some more explanation about it..

Also what is the function exactly i mean what is the difference between "user" and "files" etc..

Answer (score 5):

PHP 7.2 dropped the ability to change the session save handler to "user" using `ini_set()`.

Use [`session_set_save_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) instead, passing it a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) argument that acts as the session save handler.

You can find the announcement in the [changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.0):

> Improved [bug #73100](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73100) fix. 'user' save handler can only be set by session_set_save_handler()